# CSS Keyframe Animations progressively slowing down

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm creating a write-on animation (much like a typewriter) over several lines. All is working relatively well, but each line of text is taking longer to resolve/animate than the previous line. Any help is much appreciated.

```css
body {
  background: #272822;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
li {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30em;
  animation: type 1.5s steps(30, end);
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  animation: type2 1.5s steps(60, end);
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  animation: type2 2.5s steps(60, end);
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  animation: type2 4.25s steps(60, end);
}
li:nth-child(5) {
  animation: type2 5.5s steps(60, end);
}
li:nth-child(6) {
  animation: type2 7s steps(60, end);
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
.white {
  color: white;
}
.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
@keyframes type {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="codeWriteOn">
  <ul class="MonokaiBright">
    <li>
      <span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">ul</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;markup&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project1">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">li</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;project1&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
      <!-- ">" --><span>Project-1&#x3c;</span><span class="red">/li</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project2">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">li</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;project2&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
      <!-- ">" --><span>Project-2&#x3c;</span><span class="red">/li</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project3">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">li</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;project3&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
      <!-- ">" --><span>Project-3&#x3c;</span><span class="red">/li</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project4">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">li</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;project4&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
      <!-- ">" --><span>Project-4&#x3c;</span><span class="red">/li</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      &#x3c;</span><span class="red">/ul</span><span>&#x3e;</span> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer provided by spacegeek224](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120492/css-keyframe-animations-progressively-slowing-down/35120536#35120536) is on the right track but it is partial and that's why you still see a problem with it.

As per your code, the initial `width` of the `li` element is `30em` and in the animation's keyframes it is specified that the `width` should animate `from` `0em`. When an `animation-delay` is set on a element and `animation-fill-mode: backwards` is not specified, the element would continue to hold the state specified outside the `@keyframes` until the delay time is elapsed. This is why all the `li` were visible to you from the start itself.

If `animation-fill-mode: backwards` is specified, the element would continue to hold the state as at its first keyframe (which is `0%` or `from`) till the delay time is elapsed. So, the elements would take up the `width: 0` during the delay period and thus become invisible until their animation starts.

As per [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-fill-mode-property):

> If the value for ‘animation-fill-mode’ is ‘backwards’, then the animation will apply the property values defined in the keyframe that will start the first iteration of the animation, during the period defined by ‘animation-delay’.

Another thing to note is that if you want all the elements to animate one after the other then their delays should be set in such a way that it is equal to the total amount of time required for all the prior elements to complete their animation. So the delay on `:nth-child(2)` would be `3s`, for `:nth-child(3)` should be `4.5s` and so on.

**Demo:**

Applying both the aforementioned corrections, the below snippet would work as per your need.

```css
body {
  background: #272822;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
li {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30em;
  animation: type 1.5s steps(30, end) backwards;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 4.5s;
}
li:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
li:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
.white {
  color: white;
}
.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
@keyframes type {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="codeWriteOn">
  <ul class="MonokaiBright">
    <li>
      <span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">ul</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;markup&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project1">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">li</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;project1&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
      <!-- ">" --><span>Project-1&#x3c;</span><span class="red">/li</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project2">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">li</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;project2&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
      <!-- ">" --><span>Project-2&#x3c;</span><span class="red">/li</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project3">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">li</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;project3&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
      <!-- ">" --><span>Project-3&#x3c;</span><span class="red">/li</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project4">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">li</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;project4&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
      <!-- ">" --><span>Project-4&#x3c;</span><span class="red">/li</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      &#x3c;</span><span class="red">/ul</span><span>&#x3e;</span> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Alternate Method:**

Another way to get the animation working without adding `animation-fill-mode: backwards` would be to set the default `width` of the `li` element as `0` and then animate it `to` `30em` instead of animating it `from` `0`. This means that during the delay period the `width` would still be `0` and so the `li` would be invisible.

But, in this case `animation-fill-mode: forwards` should be added to make the `li` hold the state as at its final keyframe. Otherwise, it would go back to being invisible (`width: 0`) after completion of the animation.

```css
body {
  background: #272822;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
li {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  animation: type 1.5s steps(30, end) forwards;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 4.5s;
}
li:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
li:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
.white {
  color: white;
}
.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
@keyframes type {
  to {
    width: 30em;
  }
}
@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="codeWriteOn">
  <ul class="MonokaiBright">
    <li>
      <span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">ul</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;markup&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project1">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">li</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;project1&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
      <!-- ">" --><span>Project-1&#x3c;</span><span class="red">/li</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project2">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">li</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;project2&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
      <!-- ">" --><span>Project-2&#x3c;</span><span class="red">/li</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project3">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">li</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;project3&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
      <!-- ">" --><span>Project-3&#x3c;</span><span class="red">/li</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project4">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">li</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;project4&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
      <!-- ">" --><span>Project-4&#x3c;</span><span class="red">/li</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      &#x3c;</span><span class="red">/ul</span><span>&#x3e;</span> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Note:**

In the above snippet, it may look as though there is a lengthy delay/pause after the first line but that is not a problem with keyframes. It is because the element is still animating to its full width (`30em`) even after the entire text has become visible.

In the below snippet, I have added a `background` for each `li` element so that you can visually see what I mean.

```css
body {
  background: #272822;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
li {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30em;
  background: mediumslateblue;
  animation: type 1.5s steps(30, end) backwards;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 4.5s;
}
li:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
li:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
.white {
  color: white;
}
.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
@keyframes type {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="codeWriteOn">
  <ul class="MonokaiBright">
    <li>
      <span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">ul</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;markup&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project1">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">li</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;project1&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
      <!-- ">" --><span>Project-1&#x3c;</span><span class="red">/li</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project2">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">li</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;project2&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
      <!-- ">" --><span>Project-2&#x3c;</span><span class="red">/li</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project3">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">li</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;project3&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
      <!-- ">" --><span>Project-3&#x3c;</span><span class="red">/li</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="project4">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>&#x3c;</span><span class="red">li</span>
      <span class="green">class</span>&#61;<span class="yellow">&#8220;project4&#8221;</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
      <!-- ">" --><span>Project-4&#x3c;</span><span class="red">/li</span><span>&#x3e;</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      &#x3c;</span><span class="red">/ul</span><span>&#x3e;</span> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Harry, Thank you for your elegant solutions and your very informative comments. I learned something today.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of increasing the animation time for each one, use `animation-delay: 1s` (replace `1s` with your delay), and change the animation time for each `li` to the same number.

Example:

```
li {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30em;
  animation: type 1.5s steps(30, end);
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  animation: type2 1.5s steps(60, end);
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  animation: type2 1.5s steps(60, end);
animation-delay: 1s;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  animation: type2 1.5s steps(60, end);
animation-delay: 2.75s;
}
li:nth-child(5) {
  animation: type2 1.5s steps(60, end);
animation-delay: 4s;
}
li:nth-child(6) {
  animation: type2 1.5s steps(60, end);
animation-delay: 6.5s;
}
```

Comment: Could also just put the delays in and not repeat the animation in nth-child declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your question is, but maybe I'm going to assume that you don't want it to go slower and slower. If that's the case you need to delete these lines

```
    li:nth-child(2) {
      animation: type2 1.5s steps(60, end);
    }
    li:nth-child(3) {
      animation: type2 2.5s steps(60, end);
    }
    li:nth-child(4) {
      animation: type2 4.25s steps(60, end);
    }
    li:nth-child(5) {
      animation: type2 5.5s steps(60, end);
    }
    li:nth-child(6) {
      animation: type2 7s steps(60, end);
    }
```

Those `1.5s`, `2.5s`, etc values are slowing it down.

Comment: If you delete those lines, then all the `li`s will animate at the same time.

Comment: True, I think your answer is better. But from the description I'm not sure if that's what's desired.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. What i'm trying to do is have each line animate on, one after the other. As if someone who could really type was typing the code. The first solution nearly works - The code is animating a equal speed, one line after another, but all the lines of text are visible from the beginning.